# Couldn’t generate Swift representation Error from source kit Could not load module: GoogleSignin

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3

I use Firebase in Xcode 8 and I get the following error when I command-click import `GoogleSignIn`.

> Couldn’t generate Swift Representation
>
> Error from SourceKit
>
> "Could not load module: GoogleSignin"

The issue looks similar to the following screenshot:

Could not load module: GoogleSignIn

[image: Could not load module: GoogleSignIn]

Build settings

[image: Build settings]

I have tried:

- Going to targets Build Settings and adding a path to Framework Search
  Paths.

  ```
  /Users/{user}/path-to-framework-parent-directory
  ```
- My xcodeproject has no spaces.
- Clean/Build/restart Xcode didn’t fix this.
- Pod install in the terminal didn’t  fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me: I **removed the spaces of the base folder** of my Swift project. From

Documents/__Swift 2017/Socially

to

Documents/**__Swift2017**/Socially